# Why does this mechanism work?

Tags: binary

Why does [this](https://www.instagram.com/p/CFu5oPZj_Ts/?igshid=1w9w231tpam8r) work? Why is it counting binary numbers?

Comment: The little horizontal piece of wood acts as a carry. The rest is physics.

Comment: It produces binary numbers because the only options are 0 and 1. A better question would be why it counts.

Comment: @Alexander Gruber♦ Yeah! Please tell me.